# Installed 4GB Memory. Bios sees 4 GB. Ubuntu sees only 3GB. Why, and How can I make it see 4 GB?

Tags: memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Ubuntu only show 3GB of RAM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32272/why-does-ubuntu-only-show-3gb-of-ram)
>   [8 GB RAM on 64 bit processor using 32 bit Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43422/8-gb-ram-on-64-bit-processor-using-32-bit-ubuntu)

On 3 19 2012 I installed 4 GB of memory on my 32 bit pc, which is the maximum memory that my motherboard will except.

When I checked the BIOS it showed 4 GB.

When I went into Ubuntu 11.10 and looked at the memory settings, it showed 3 GB.

How can I get Ubuntu 11.10 to see all 4 GB of memory.

Thanks

Comment: Have you installed the 32 or 64bit version of Ubuntu?

Comment: It's 32bits, look at the question. @Rob, check the above link answers, they should help you.